# Configure vim's :make to switch or open tabs on error

Tags: vim, make

When I run `:make` from vim and there's an error, it opens that file on the error line number in the current buffer. If possible, I would prefer it switch tabs to the file if it's already open, or make a new tab with the error file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a quickfix window:

> In the quickfix window, each line is one error.  The line number is equal to
>   the error number.  You can use ":.cc" to jump to the error under the cursor.
>   Hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or double-clicking the mouse on a line has the same
>   effect.  The file containing the error is opened in the window above the
>   quickfix window.  If there already is a window for that file, it is used
>   instead.

(from Vim's quickfix.txt, Section 2)

Just type

```
:help quickfix-window
```

in vim to get there.

For example

```
:copen
```

opens a quickfix window.

Comment: I looked a quickfix before posting this, but your instructions make it clearer. It's probably the way to go, thanks.